# How to get clicked hyperlink row adjacent cell value from GridView in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I'm working with one of my projects in C# ASP.NET. I have a `GridView` in webform page which is fetching data from database. it has three columns **Checkbox**, **DeptId** and **DeptName**. **DeptName** is in `hyperlink` field i need that when user clicks **deptName** hyperlink its **DeptId** must be saved to a string and passed to other class as a parameter of selected department.i am confused how to do that !! Please Help me

I did this but it didn't helped

```
 protected void DepartmentTable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string name = DepartmentTable.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
      Departmentlist obj = new Departmentlist();
      obj.setDeptid(name);
 }
```

HTML MARKUP CODE

```
<asp:GridView ID="DepartmentTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="814px" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" DataKeyNames="DeptId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DepartmentTable_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptId" HeaderText="DeptId" SortExpression="DeptId" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeptName">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("DeptId", "Departmentlist.aspx?DeptId={0}") %>' Text='<%# Eval("DeptName") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Can you post your markup code?

Comment: Yeah sam check it out now i have added please help me

Comment: Do you need to set Departmentlist obj in the SelectedIndexChanged event? You are already passing the DeptId as QueryString parameter. Why can't you use it in the Page_Load event of Departmentlist.aspx page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the control as a hyperlink and get thje text of the hyperlink control. Something like:

string name = ((HyperLink)DepartmentTable.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;

Comment: Aaron Thanks for replying but e.RowIndex is giving error that System.EventArgs does contain a defination for e.RowIndex and no extension method 'RowIndex' Accepting a first argument of type System.EventArgs could be found

Comment: It is part of the row command event. I thought that's what you were using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626%28v=vs.100%29.aspx Try the edit I just made.